Noticed these bulges and a spot that looks like a leak
I bought a new build and noticed these bulges in the walls and a spot in the ceiling. there isn't another floor above, it is just the roof. should I be concerned about these issues? the bathroom fan drips water when I take a longer shower, is this normal?

enter image description here


Your first photo just looks like bad taping to me, but I can't be sure.  Get a moisture meter to check.  Your second photo is a water leak, either a leak from outside or a dripping pipe.
